# Add-ADGroupMember for multiple members from different domains Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have problem with adding multiple users from different domains:

```
$nazwa = 'test'
$lista = Import-CSV "\test.csv"
ForEach ($user in $lista)
{Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $nazwa -Members $user.username}
```

I can type port, but don't have everything in main catalog, so Im using SAMAccountName to get users from other domains:

```
Get-ADUser -Server "test.pl:3268" -LDAPFilter "(SAMAccountName=$User.username)"
```

How can I use this domain with port to make ForEach correctly. Or do I have to search each domain separately?

Comment: How many usernames are in your list? You could construct an LDAP filter that looks for _any of them_, then you only have to query each domain once.

Comment: Around 50 sometime less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to search each domain separately?

Yes - but you don't necessarily have to query each domain for every single user.

LDAP's filter syntax supports `|` (OR) clauses, so we can construct a filter that would match *any* of the usernames in question:

```
$filterClauses = $lista |ForEach-Object {
  "(SAMAccountName=$($_.username))"
}
$ldapFilter = "(|$(-join $filterClauses))"
```

Now the `$ldapFilter` string will look like `(|(SAMAccountName=username1)(SAMAccountName=username2)(...))`, and we can do with a single query against each domain:

```
$userTable = @{}

foreach($domain in 'domain1.fqdn','domain2.fqdn','domain3.fqdn'){
    Get-ADUser -Server "$domain`:3268" -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter |ForEach-Object {
        $userTable[$_.SAMAccountName] = $_
    }
}
```

At which point we can rewrite your loop to:

```
foreach($user in $lista){
    if($userTable.ContainsKey($user.username)){
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $nazwa -Members $userTable[$user.username]
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No user with username $($user.username) was found!"
    }
}
```